# OpenGL,SOIL library and a textured rectangular

Tags: c, opengl, glut, soil

I'm trying to make a simple textured rectangular in OpenGL using SOIL and GLUT.

This is my Display function (executed in main by glutDisplayFunc(Display)):

```
void Display ()
{
    GLuint tex_2d;

    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    gluLookAt (eyex,eyey,eyez,centerx,centery,centerz,0,1,0);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
        "img.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
     if( 0 == tex_2d )
    {
        printf( "SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result() );
        exit(1);
    }

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_2d);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); 

    glColor3f (0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

                       glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
                       glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
                       glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
                       glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);

     glEnd();   
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glFlush ();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

With this is see only a black rectangular without any texture. I'm trying to do something with this for a few hours. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're loading the texture every frame?

Comment: I know I shouldn't do that, but even when I'm loading texture somewhere else it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you set the color to black just before you draw the rectangle? The line

```
glColor3f (0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

Try white instead...

```
glColor3f (1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

Comment: Lol... I wouldn't thought that black covers the texture and white doesn't... Thanks a lot!